# Inherit height from inside div to outside div

Tags: html, css

I have a div with the below content.

```
<div class="outsideDiv">
  <div>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="imgContainer">
    <img />
  </div>
</div>
```

The imgContainer is right of the div which contains the p

The outsideDiv doesn't have a pre-defined height. It adjusts to the height of the p element. So if the p element has 500px height then the height of outside div will be 500px. My website is responsive, therefore the height of p (and so the height of outsideDiv) it isn't fixed and it changes depending on screen. This section works perfect.

I want the height of imgContainer to be equal with the height of the outsideDiv.
I have tried with position absolute and relative and it works but I don't want to use this way. Also I tried inherit height but no luck.

Comment: you want this done by using css only ?

Comment: Let say p = 500px and outsideDiv = 500px, now you want `imgContainer` to be equal than outsideDiv, i.e. 500px, but now `outsideDiv` will be 1000px, then?

Comment: My direction is left to right. That means that the image is right to p

Comment: Alright, then you need to use `flex-box`.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey thanks! flex-box works exactly in the way which I want

Answer (score 0):

```css
.imgContainer {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  bottom: -100%;
}
.outsideDiv {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="outsideDiv">
  <div>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    
  </div>

  <div class="imgContainer">
    <img />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using flexbox.

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
.outsideDiv{
  background:red;
  display:flex;
}
.outsideDiv > div{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
.outsideDiv p{
  height:500px; 
}
.imgContainer{
  background:blue;
  float:right;
  width:50%;
  height:100%:
}
```

```html
<div class="outsideDiv">
  <div>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="imgContainer">
    <img />
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/r73kh3bo/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use **Flexbox** because of browser support, here's another example: https://jsfiddle.net/r73kh3bo/1/

Basically you can just create a parent div with `display: table` and each child inside with `display: table-cell` will have the same height.